# Shearing a wall smart DYI project?

Tags: walls, engineering, shear

I'm pretty handy and can follow engineering plans, but wondering whether taking on a sheer wall project is something an advanced DYI'r should take on?

Comment: Shear wall vs. sheer wall? I don't know what either one is, so a little explanation (and spelling consistency) would help. Also DIY, not DYI.

Comment: Are you talking about installing shear braces on an existing wall, or putting a shearwall in where none existed before?

Comment: What state do you live in? Is it seismically active or has high winds? (Not all shear walls are the same.)

Comment: No matter how you shear it, this is opinion based. If _you_ feel you're up to the task, then go for it. If you don't, then don't. No two "DIYers" are at the same level of confidence on the same task, and we don't know you, so we can't answer the question for you.

Comment: go talk with your local jurisdiction about your plans. They will help and you'll walk away knowing if it's a good idea for you to do yourself.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback! I live in San Jose, California. Id image this work would have an inspector to sign it off, but not sure if that is always the case for this type of work.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of details to consider, but if you can follow plans you can probably get it done.

Last year I designed a garage myself but needed to have the front wall engineered for both wind load and shear.  I tried to do the calcs myself but the city wanted a structural engineer to sign off on it.

Anyhow, while the plans weren't that complex on paper, building such a large wall and doing some more complicated framing up high was a big job but I got it done.

So if you have the specs, and can follow that you'll be fine.

There are so many variations on shear walls it's too hard to say just how easy or complicated it may be.  Some require additional fastening to the foundation, some require a lot of metal strapping.  Some require structural sheathing to be used on both sides of the wall or a closer nailing pattern.

I'd say give it a go!